# Tomcat is running from terminal but not from Eclipse and Spring Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9

I am trying to start `Tomcat 9.0` server from `Eclipse` and `Spring Tool Suite`. But is always ending with the error "Can't start in 45 seconds". I increased the time, still the same error.

I have given the installed Tomcat directory and a new tomcat zip extract directory to check whether it is an issue with the tomcat installation.

**But the tomcat server is running from the terminal if I use the command**

```
/Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

**And stopping with the command**

```
/Library/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

How can I make the server running from Eclipse and STS? Any help is appreciated

Note: I am using Mac Catalina as my OS

Comment: I double checked, used a fresh Tomcat 9.0.33 and STS 3.9.12 install, chose the Tomcat 9 server adaptor and AdoptOpenJDK 1.8 to run it and it works right away. Which versions of those tools do you use?

Comment: @MartinLippert, Thanks for the hint. I am using Tomcat 9.0.33. I gave the Tomcat details. Where should I provide the AdoptOpenJDK details? I have the AdoptOpenJDK version 11

Comment: if you create the server adaptor for it (from the Servers view), you can select the JDK that should be used to run the server with. If you already have the server adaptor, there is a launch config created for it where you could change the JDK/JRE to launch it.